# Estimate ride price (Uber)

Tags: php, uber-api

Well, I'm trying to create a price request for the uber ride using the api, but I'm not succeeding .. I do not understand what's happening with the code to give these errors, I'll take prints and put the code here , If you can help me, I'd appreciate it...

This is the error:

---

> Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: fields_string in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
>   on line 11 {"error": "invalid_grant"}

---

***My index.php:***

```
<?php

function fetchUrl($url,$code){
    $fields = array(
        'client_id' => "ibhY[.....]BI6",
        'client_secret' => "vMq[.....]6-ga[.....]rqU-[.....]",
        'grant_type' => "authorization_code",
        'redirect_uri' => "http://localhost:80/request.php",
        'code' => $code
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
$data = fetchUrl('https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token', $_GET['code']);
$data = json_decode($data);
print_r($data);
```

***My request.php***

---

```
<?php

$token = "KA.eyX[....................................]5jk";


$header = array(
    "Authorization: Token $token",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept-Language: en_US");

// CALCULATE FAIR

$url = "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075";


$curl    = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $token);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output1 = curl_exec($curl);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output1);
```

[image from my uber control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYIHQ.png)

Comment: If I use the authorization link given by the uber control panel gives the following error:

" {"message":"No authentication provided.","code":"unauthorized"} "

Comment: Looks like your authorization flow is not valid. If you get {"error": "invalid_grant"} then this means the code inside the query parameter code has already been used once or has become invalid. Can you explain how did you use "authorization link given by the uber control panel"? Did you get access_token? And used this token to get an estimate?

Answer (score 0):

The following error:

`Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 20`

refers to the following line of code:

```
$data = fetchUrl('https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token', $_GET['code']);
```

This suggests the authorization code is not being passed into your `index.php` script.

You need to get authorization from a user in order to receive the code.  Documentation on how to do this can be found here:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token#step-1-user-authorizes-your-app

Once you have this code, you will be able to request and access token and make requests on behalf of the user (e.g. getting price estimates).